# api/account redirect to login even after login jhipster

Tags: jhipster

when i hit **api/authentication** **jhispter** found user and print but when i hit api/account then it print anonymous user.

we have jhipster angular application up and running perfectly without any issue but we want to add react native application with **jhipster** backend. we are getting the issue on authentication and API/account API after successful login when I hit `API/account` or any custom `API/**` it failed because **jhipster** considers **react-native** user anonymous user.

why **jhipster** considers an anonymous user to every application except angular one.

I am facing this issue when I am trying to add another front-end app. currently generated jhipster application working except not working.

Request URL: localhost:8080/api/account

Request Method: GET

Status Code: 302 Found

Remote Address: [::1]:8080

Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgra

**Response Headers**

Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: localhost:8081

Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate

Connection: keep-alive

Content-Length: 0

Date: Fri, 19 Jul 2019 10:29:44 GMT

Expires: 0

Location: localhost:8080/login

Pragma: no-cache

Vary: Origin

X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

(https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/14179110/61437914-9d6e2100-a957-11e9-9bd3-854e7d7dbcc8.png)

Comment: Which authentication type did you select? If it requires a token, how to you pass it to server on subsequent requests?

Comment: we are using session base authentication.

Comment: Have you checked that the session cookie is sent with your request? Session is probably not the easiest choice for mobile but I suppose that something like react-native-cookies could help.

Comment: Yes but when I created sample index.html and consumed jhipster API I got still the same issue

Comment: If you reproduced with an index.html, it should be easy for you to paste the full trace of HTTP requests with their headers.

Comment: Request URL: http://localhost:8080/api/account
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302 Found
Remote Address: [::1]:8080
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgra


**Response  Headers**

Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8081
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Date: Fri, 19 Jul 2019 10:29:44 GMT
Expires: 0
Location: http://localhost:8080/login
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Origin
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

Comment: I meant paste it into the question not in comments, it's not very readable. I can't see any cookie in request, so it would seem normal that you are seen as anonymous user. and in the logs you see "SessionId: null". Why 2 ports 8080 and 8081? What is your architecture? Please edit your question