# why jhipster considering user anonymous even after login

Tags: jhipster

when I hit `API/login` successful login

**AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE : AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS**

**AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE : false**

**ANONYMOUS_USER : false**

**ANONYMOUS_USER : test@gmail.com**

when I hit `API/account` its failed please check below screenshot.

**AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE : AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE**

**AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE : true**

**ANONYMOUS_USER : false**

**ANONYMOUS_USER : anonymousUser**

(https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/14179110/61437914-9d6e2100-a957-11e9-9bd3-854e7d7dbcc8.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [api/account redirect to login even after login jhipster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57106835/api-account-redirect-to-login-even-after-login-jhipster)

Comment: Please do not open 2 questions for same problem and edit your first question with requested details.